# Selecting a href without an ID and changing the inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select a href that doesn't have an ID and change the inner html.  I cannot access the html, but I can use js/css.  The href is within an li that does have an id that I can select.  So the html looks like this

```
<li id="sampleID">
    <a title="sampletitle" href="somewhere.com">somewhere</a>
</li>
```

I'm currently using something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">var links =  document.querySelector('#sampleID').getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(el) {
    // set attribute
    el.setAttribute('id','sample');
});

var element=document.getElementById('sample'); 
element.innerhtml="somewhereElse";

</script>
```

But this isn't working (it isn't setting the href to an ID, so obviously not changing the innerhtml).

Edit: Sorry I didn't specify earlier, but Jquery is an option (I'm already calling the library in this environment).  So if there is a really simple jquery solution, that would be perfect.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using jQuery? It would simplify your problem by a lot

Comment: @Turk I don't think bringing an entire library to solve one specific problem counts as simplification.

Comment: I don't disagree, but jQuery is so commonly used nowadyas for DOM manipulation that it would be good practice to get used to it he/she isn't already. And chances are this isn't the only area he/she needs to manipulate

Comment: Don't mess with changing the id. Just do `element = document.getElementById('sampleID').children[0]` or `document.querySelector( '#sampleID a' )` to get the anchor, and the rest should work.

Comment: @Turk you may want to familiarize yourself with how easy DOM manipulation is with native JS now a days, especially with ES6 features.

Comment: Even without ES6 features, as long as you don't have to support farther back than IE8, jQuery isn't that much more useful than vanilla js for DOM manipulation. Besides, it's not uncommon to find oneself in situations where jQuery isn't available and can't be imported.

Comment: jQuery is still best for cross-browser support which every webdev should be looking out for. If you get into webdev without jQuery, you're crazy. There's no reason not to use it or introduce yourself to it with an easy opportunity such as this one. If we didn't do things that were totally overkill sometimes then we would never know how to properly use them when they aren't overkill. Personally I see this problem as a learning opportunity to move into another stage of webdev.

Comment: @Turk personally I prefer to develop for those that stay current on technology. I have no desire to cater to the X% of people using legacy software. In that situation, browser compatibility is rarely an issue. But, I do agree. My old job required me to support IE7+, so jQuery was applicable there.

Comment: @Turk, I mostly agree. I moved into webdev from another field and if not for jQuery I wouldn't have landed my first dev job. People like to diss jQuery but I would bet that jQuery know-how employs tens of thousands of developers across the United States

Comment: @Turk a proper polyfill like modernizr is often a better choice than a heavy-handed (slow and non-standard) code dump like jQuery.

Comment: Polyfills and transpiled code ftw

Comment: You sure about that? A huge number of people are still running legacy software because they can't be bothered to update. And it is our jobs to make sure our software is up to snuff to handle whatever is thrown at it. If you are losing any % of you're market because they can't access your site because you didn't account for IE 6 or older, or some other browser situation. You could easily be let go for that, or at least you can where I work. Programming should be done in such a way that nothing can break your code. I am not sure how anyone could possibly develop under a different mindset.

Comment: but does jQuery support IE5.5? better make sure you have 100% coverage.... ohh and no js because lynx.

Comment: Have you ever done the math between the cost to making your code legacy compatible versus the revenue potential lost from not developing to the older systems?

Comment: @ssube I'm not disagreeing but jQuery is the dirty little secret of many modern dynamic web pages, however since it isn't Angular or react.js or something-google.js, it gets constantly disrespected

Comment: Personally? no. But I work in market research developing custom surveys that thousands and sometimes millions of people will be taking across every single browser imaginable. So my company has done the math and has the data to back it up, and man are those some large numbers. Does jQuery account for every edge case in every browser? No of course not, that would be to magical. But it makes the job that much easier and removes a lot of headaches from our day to day. I'm not saying everyone be an expert here. Just know what you're options are and why you would want to use them.

Comment: need an abstraction your entire team can use so you don't have 19 different dom utilities written by each team member? jQuery et al is probably great. "just use it for free browser compat which you may or may not need" is not a valid argument for using it.

Comment: @rlemon in webdev, is there ever a time where cross browser support isn't needed?

Comment: all the time. I develop specifically for modern mobiles. I don't need or want jQuery

Comment: I don't think this is the place to get into this debate. I get what you're saying @Turk, and I don't think you're wrong. But if OP wants a jQuery solution, they can probably find one pretty easily. Since they didn't specify any libraries, a vanilla js solution is much more educational and valuable in this case.

Comment: @rlemon, check this link, 1st paragraph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery  jQuery = jobs, plain and simple, and it still be around when react.js and vue.js have died

Comment: Trust me this conversation is well beyond the scope of OP now. lol But shockingly civil so I'm all for going nuts.

Comment: jQuery is life.

Comment: no one is arguing that jQuery isn't a good thing to learn, but the argument that you need it in all projects is not true.

Comment: @rlemon, I would certainly agree with that. My main point beforehand was simply if OP had heard about jQuery or not. depending on his specific application it may or may not have been helpful. I should probably show more restraint in throwing new topics at similar questions to OP's

Comment: @Kevin B, jQuery is literally my only reason for getting out of bed each morning

Answer (score 4):

Use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
var link = document.querySelector( '#sampleID a' );
var linkHref = link.href;

// Change text of link
link.innerText = 'hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var links =  document.querySelector('#sampleID a');

       Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(el) {
           // set attribute
           el.setAttribute('id','sample');
       });

       var element=document.getElementById('sample'); 
       element.innerhtml="somewhereElse";

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The negation operator in CSS selectors is `:not()` so :

```
var links = document.querySelector('a:not([id])');
```

or is there's more than one match :

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a:not([id])');
```

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0):

If pure JS is needed (you didn't set jQuery as a tag), and multiple anchors inside desired `<li>` tag, and only one anchor within this `<li>` has no id try this:

```
var li_content = document.getElementById("sampleID"),
    anchors    = li_content.getElementsByTagName("A"),
    length     = anchors.length,
    i          = 0;

for(; i < length; i++) {
    if (!anchors[i].getAttribute("id")) {
        // your function is called here
    }
}
```

Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rh3mqLx/2/) - this seems to be what you are looking for

Comment: Thought this worked before but just re-checked and you're correct. Will edit